# I can't run rshiny prefectly in vscode T_T

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, shiny

When I am runing shiny in vscode I can't draw a plot. Even the example

```
shiny::runExample("01_hello")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTAJ4.png)

this is my `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                               LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0 cli_3.3.0      jsonlite_1.8.0 rlang_1.0.2
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this - the above line works as expected for me in vscode. If anyone is going to be able to solve this you will need to provide your `sessionInfo()` output but I think this is going to be hard for anyone else to troubleshoot. I would make sure you have the most recent version of all packages and vscode.

Comment: I got it, the r version is too new, must the 4.1.3, I'm the 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The R version is too new, must set up the 4.1.3

Comment: Please leave a more detailed comment on what you did to solve the problem, like how did you downgrade R, if you did that, otherwise how you solved it. The question and answer looks too niche so more details would help if someone comes here looking just like you.